# Check if a file in SharePoint has finished uploading

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am building a pipeline which SharePoint will be the source for data ingestion. I want to use Azure LogicApps with a trigger to run when a file is created or modified. When a file is uploaded to SharePoint, LogicApps should copy the file to Blob Storage. I am facing a problem which the trigger can happen even if the file is not 100% uploaded yet, which leads to copying empty or incomplete files.

I tried several SharePoint triggers to see if it's only a problem with one of them but they all have the same issue.

I decided to use Python with `Office365-REST-Python-Client` deployed in Azure Functions to handle copying the files to Azure Blob Storage. I have the following code:

```
def download_file(context, sharepoint_file_path, local_file_path):
  response = File.open_binary(context, sharepoint_file_path)

  response.raise_for_status()

  with open(local_file_path, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(response.content)
```

I checked the response's `status_code` and even for incomplete files it returns `200` which still does not help with checking if the file is complete.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is difficult for us to check if the file in sharepoint has finished uploading. But we can avoid the situation of the file hasn't been finished uploading by some workaround.

You need to estimate how long the uploading process will take according to the size of your files, and then add a "[Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay)" action after the trigger.
[image]

For example, it delay 5 minutes in the screenshot above. After 5 minutes, the file complete the upload operation and will be copied to blob storage successful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only possible way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @SamehSharaf You can also get the file's [last modified date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUoDz.png) and add a "Condition" or "Until" to judge if utcNow() minus lastModifiedDate is greater than 1 minute(you can use ticks() method to convert the timestamp to number and compare them). In this way, we do not need to estimate how long the uploading process will take.

Comment: worth trying. Thank you!